# Отправка почты через консоль не уходит по команде mail -s "test" root

Tags: email, postfix

Настроил postfix на centos 7. Почтовый сервер работает, почта уходит. Пытаюсь прикрутить postfix к консоли, сделав отправку почты по умолчанию через консоль. В /etc/aliases указал 
root: root, admin@mymail
по команде 
mail -s "test" admin@mymail почта уходит и приходит, все хорошо.
Но  не работает отправка почты пользотвателю root
mail -s "test" root - не работает
mail -s "test" root@localhost так же не работе
В /var/log/maillog ошибок нет

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае после "mail -s "test" root " система ждет тела письма, завершив писать которое надо нажать CTRL-D

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вашем случае удобно все сделать одной строкой:

```
echo "тестовое сообщение" | mail -s "Горячее для root" root
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]